# Xamarin Forms Azure SQL connection is not responding

Tags: sql-server, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin project working with azure sql database. It was working fine till today but I had to change my db and all server. From now whenever i want to open my connection app freeze and says is not responding. I tried to change my connection string but as I said it used to works fine. Here is my codes;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Check Conn" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs [sqlconn is proper its for an example]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string dbname = "dbname";
            string srvrname = "servrnm";
            string username = "username";
            string password = "password";
            string sqlconn = $"Data Source={srvrname}.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog={dbname};User ID={username};Password={password}" ;
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
        }

            private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ALERT", "CONNECTION OPENED", "Ok");
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk9Hb.png)

Comment: first, connecting directly from a mobile app to your db server is a horrible idea and you should not do it.  However, if you must - if it was working before and is not now, I would first check all of your server config - is it open to remote connections, is there a firewall, does it require whitelisted ips, etc to verify that it is identical to your prior config

Comment: @Jason I checked and already gave permission to ip adresses from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 and also gave my direct own ip too.

Comment: have you tested your code in a console app?